# How do I set Local module directory for sonar scanner for MSBuild in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

My jenkins project does 2 checkouts, one from a framework and one from an application A that uses the framework.

I want to run a sonar scanner on application A.

I Have 6 building steps in jenkins

`Execute Windows batch command : nuget.exe restore "%WORKSPACE%\Framework\branches\1.0.1.0\Framework.sln"`

`Execute Windows batch command : nuget.exe restore "%WORKSPACE%\AppUsingFramework\branches\v1.1.3\AppUsingFramework.sln"`

```
Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild : build framework

SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild - Begin Analysis // HOW DO I SET THE FOLDER TO %WORKSPACE%\AppUsingFramework\branches\v1.1.3 ?

Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild : build the application
MSBuild Build File  : AppUsingFramework\branches\v1.1.3\AppUsingFramework.sln

SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild - End Analysis
```

I get this message :

> The SonarQube MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects.
>
> Possible causes:
>
> 1. The project has not been built - the project must be built in between the begin and end steps
> 2. An unsupported version of MSBuild has been used to build the project. Currently MSBuild 14.0 upwards are supported
> 3. The begin, build or end steps have not all been launched from the same folder
>
> Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete SonarQube analysis.

So I suspect that I should specify working folder (%WORKSPACE%\AppUsingFramework\branches\v1.1.3) to sonar when I start it, how do I do that ?

I use :

Jenkins 2.60.2

SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 3.0.1.635 (install automatically from github)

MSBuild 15

Comment: Did you start the analysis from the root of the solution (executed a change directory if needed)?

Comment: I don't know, i'm looking for a way to specify the path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By removing the unnecessary build framework step (it's built in the app already) and by only specifiying AppUsingFramework.sln without path the sonar scan succeed.